# How to add edges from one graph to another graph in R (same vertexes for both graphs)?

Tags: r, igraph

I am struggling to understand how to merge two graphs together with `igraph`.

It seems possible to add the vertices of one graph to the other (thanks to the `add_vertices()` function), but impossible to add the edges of one graph to the other (despite the `add_edges()` function).

Here is a code to reproduce my problem, and the final error message that I get.

I first create two graphs, each with specific vertices and edges.

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

d1 <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6), to = c(5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 1, 5))
graph1 <- graph_from_data_frame(d1, directed = FALSE, vertices = NULL)
V(graph1)
E(graph1)

d2 <- data.frame(from = c(7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 12), to = c(11, 8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 7, 11))
graph2 <- graph_from_data_frame(d2, directed = FALSE, vertices = NULL)
V(graph2)
V(graph2)$Size <- c(56, 58, 75, 81, 65, 45)
vertex.attributes(graph2)
E(graph2)
```

Now, I would like to obtain a graph containing the vertices and edges from the two previous graphs.

It works fine for the vertices:

```
graph3 <- add_vertices(graph1, length(V(graph2)), attr = vertex.attributes(graph2))
V(graph3)
vertex.attributes(graph3)
```

But I fail for the edges, irrespective of what I tried:

```
# 1st try
graph3 <- add_edges(graph1, E(graph2))

# 2nd try
E(graph3) <- add_edges(graph1, E(graph2))

# 3rd try (very cumbersome)
edges2 <- get.edgelist(graph2)
edges2 <- data.frame(source = edges2[, 1], target = edges2[, 2])

edges2for3 <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(edges2$source)) {
  edges2for3 <- append(edges2for3, as.numeric(edges2[i, ]))
}

# edges2for3 is indeed a vector, which seems to me very close to the "vertex sequence" referred to in ?add_edges
edges2for3

add_edges(graph1, edges2for3)
```

I always the following message error, that I do not understand:

```
Error in add_edges(graph1, E(graph2)) : 
  At type_indexededgelist.c:272 : cannot add edges, Invalid vertex id
```

Why is the vertex id invalid? All edges come from existing vertices...

Any help welcome :-)

Comment: does `union` work?

Comment: Yes, it does work! `graph3 <- union(graph1, graph2)`. Many thanks. The documentation of igraph is not so easy to go through... but the answer was there as well ;-) Anyway, you saved my day :-)